# How to reference named range as sheet name in query function?

Tags: google-sheets-query

`=QUERY(ActiveMonth!A7:L,"select A,D where K matches 'Admission|Pending'",0)`

I am using sheets name/tabs  (January, February.. December).
ActiveMonth is a namedRange of a cell containing the Month Name (A1). I want to query the tab with the activeMonth name. If the ActiveMonth (A1) is January then the formula will run as `=QUERY(January!A7:L,"select A,D where K matches 'Admission|Pending'",0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=QUERY(indirect(ActiveMonth&"!A7:L"),"select A,D where K matches 'Admission|Pending'",0)`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850828/dynamic-sheet-name-in-query-in-google-spreashsheet

Comment: Since your named range consists of just 1 cell *"...ActiveMonth is a namedRange of a cell containing the Month Name (A1)"*, you can skip the named range all together and just replace it by the cell itself. In this case it would be `indirect(A1&"!A7:L")`